# Show portrait video to landscape on Videojs player as HLS ffmpeg Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, video.js

I am currently using the ffmpeg library through laravel sdk. For the landscape videos I have no problem with the scaling filters application, but with the portrait videos I need the video to look like the thumbnail below:

[image]

But when I play the video, the player is distorted.

[image]

**Note: It should be noted that when I work with horizontal scales, the player looks good, but the video is distorted.**

[image]

[image]

this is my PHP Laravel code implementation

```
            FFMpeg::FromDisk('local')->open($this->media)
            ->exportForHLS()
            ->setSegmentLength(6) // optional
            /*
            ->addFormat($lowBitrate, function ($media) {
                $media->addFilter(function ($filters, $in, $out) {
                    $filters->custom($in, 'scale=854x480,setsar=1,setdar=16:9', $out); // $in, $parameters, $out

                });
            })*/
            // Portrait test
            ->addFormat($lowBitrate, function ($media) { 
                $media->addFilter(function ($filters, $in, $out) {
                    // $filters->custom($in, "scale='w=min(720,trunc((480*33/40*dar)/2+0.5)*2):h=min(480,trunc((704*40/33/dar)/2+0.5)*2)',pad='w=720:h=480:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2',setsar='r=40/33'", $out); // $in, $parameters, $out
                    $filters->custom($in, "scale=239:-1", $out); // $in, $parameters, $out
                });
            })
            /*
            ->addFormat($midBitrate, function ($media) {
                $media->scale(1280, 720);
            })
            ->addFormat($highBitrate, function ($media) {
                $media->scale(1920, 1080);
            })*/
            ->save("public/hls/$video->id/$video->hash_name.m3u8");
```

This is the command that runs at the server level for **portrait** videos.

> [2020-12-10 17:48:17] local.INFO: ffmpeg running command
> '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-threads' '12' '-i'
> '/home/vagrant/homesteadprojects/maquillate/storage/app/videos_directory/pexels-cottonbro-6054875.mp4'
> '-filter_complex' '[0]scale=640:-2[v0]' '-map' '[v0]' '-vcodec'
> 'libx264' '-b:v' '1200k' '-g' '48' '-hls_playlist_type' 'vod'
> '-hls_time' '6' '-hls_segment_filename'
> '/home/vagrant/homesteadprojects/maquillate/storage/app/public/hls/35/NXp9waz4AO5Q14Lu6T3JbjSRY496RrtiPGIz6IOJ_0_1200_%05d.ts'
> '-acodec' 'aac' '-b:a' '128k'
> '/home/vagrant/homesteadprojects/maquillate/storage/app/public/hls/35/NXp9waz4AO5Q14Lu6T3JbjSRY496RrtiPGIz6IOJ_0_1200.m3u8'

I don't really know if my problem is at the server or frontend level, but I would greatly appreciate any contribution.

Comment: Hmm...clearly your issue is an aspect-ratio issue.  One thing to try, if you haven't already, would be to do a search, after choosing (filtering) on just the ffmpeg.  Then add the phrase 'aspect ratio' or maybe 'maintain aspect ratio' and do the search.  You may see something that would help.

Comment: I believe there's a way in video.js to resize the video-window to match the aspect ratio or resolution of the video file that is currently being displayed.  I'm wondering whether that  approach might solve it?

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem by adding a 16:9 aspect ratio to videojs, I had it set to fluid.